# Find all reals $x$ such that $(x^3+2x)^\frac{1}{5}=(x^5-2x)^\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all reals $x$ such that

$$(x^3+2x)^\frac{1}{5}=(x^5-2x)^\frac{1}{3}$$

I reduced the question to find all positive $t$ such that

$$(t+2)^3=t(t^2-2)^5$$

The solutions are $x=0$ , $x=-\sqrt{2}$, $x=\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $$(t+2)^3 - t (t^2-2)^5 = -{t}^{11}+10\,{t}^{9}-40\,{t}^{7}+80\,{t}^{5}-79\,{t}^{3}+6\,{t}^{2}+
44\,t+8$$
factors as
$$- \left( t-2 \right)  \left( t+1 \right)  \left( {t}^{9}+{t}^{8}-7\,{t
}^{7}-5\,{t}^{6}+21\,{t}^{5}+11\,{t}^{4}-27\,{t}^{3}-5\,{t}^{2}+20\,t+
4 \right) 
$$
so you immediately have two solutions $t=2$ and $t=-1$.  The third factor
is irreducible over the rationals and has Galois group $S_9$, so it is
not solvable by radicals.  It does have one real root, which is approximately $t=-.2014355876$.

Comment: This was a high school examination problem and calculator was also not allowed so is there any another method not using Galois Theory??